# Regex capture and replace %20 after last forward slash

Tags: regex, bash, perl, replace, command-line

I have a tsv file with a lot of HTML inside.

I need to replace `%20` after last forward slash of href attributes of non .jpg links.
I'm trying with Perl on command line, I need help with the regex.

I have tried some regex, this is in the live test (link next below):

```
<a\ [^>]*href="([^"]+(%20)+)[^\.jpg][^\/]"[^>]?>
```

It matches only one `<a>` tag and captures only the last occurrence of `%20`.

[Here a live test with a sample of tsv.](https://regex101.com/r/cS3iB6/1)

I could have:

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/to-some-folder/another%20folder/one%20more520folder/34%20-%20kv34%20-%20tomba%20di%20thumtmose%20iii">text</a>
```

I must match all of `%20` after the last forward slash and replace them with `-`.

or:

```
<a href="http://example.com/path/to-some-folder/another%20folder/one%20more520folder/uploads/2012/02/some%20folder/another%20folder/09%20antichi%20egizi%20-%20Tomba%20di%20Tutankhamen.jpg"> <img border="0" src="http://example.com/path/to-some-folder/another%20folder/one%20more520folder/uploads/2012/02/some%20folder/another%20folder/09%20antichi%20egizi%20-%20Tomba%20di%20Tutankhamen%20ante.jpg" width="80" height="92" alt="09 antichi egizi - Tomba di Tutankhamen" /></a>
```

I **must not** match .jpg's href attributes so the last example above need to remain untouched.

I have also tried this one that matches all expected`<a>` tags but I don't know how to capture only all of `%20` after the last slash to subsequently apply the replace:

```
<a [^>]*href="([^"]+)[^\.jpg][^\/]"[^>]?>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cS3iB6/2

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser to extract only the href attribute for the a tag. [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552)

Comment: `[^\.jpg]` this doesn't mean what you think it is..

Comment: Hey karthik - If i learned correctly from your regex yesterday - It could be (?!\.jpg) instead.

Comment: @Falt4rm yeah.. it could be...

Comment: @glenn jackman, thank you for the link, I'm in the case of Kaitlin Duck Sherwood who explain exactly what I need now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> replace %20 after last forward slash of href attributes of non .jpg links

You can use the following to match:

```
%20(?=(?:(?!\.jpg">)[^>\/])*>)
```

And replace with `-`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cS3iB6/3)

Comment: The basic flaw of this approach is that you do not check if you are in a `<a>` tag, you just check if there is no `.jpg` after the match. What if the extension is `png`? You need to extend the alternative list. The real way to get all the matches inside some markers is `\G` operator.

Comment: @stribizhev You right.. and i did so because we are not validating the pattern.. just replacing from pre existing pattern.. so there is no issue in the assumption i made.. also.. OP wants for `non .jpg` links..for which i think my solution is good enough..

Comment: @stribizhev In this case I have only jpg but would be interesting see how  would you do with the \G operator?

Answer (score 2):

In order to match `%20` inside some delimiters, you can also make use of `\G` operator (see ["Where You Left Off: The \G Assertion"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch05_06.htm#ch05-sect-posit)):

> You can use `\G` to specify the position just after the previous match.

The regex you can use is

```
(<a\b[^<]*?|(?<!^)\G)([^\/]*?)%20(?=(?![^\/]*\.jpg">)[^\/"]*">)
```

Replace with

```
\1\2-
```

Here is [my demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS2rS5/2)

In Perl-like notation, that will look like

```
s/(<a\b[^<]*?|(?<!^)\G)([^\/]*?)%20(?=(?![^\/]*\.jpg">)[^\/"]*">)/\1\2-/g
```

Comment: I do not think this solution is good with large texts, but it is precise.